# Filtering data from Spark dataframe based on datatype

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I am extracting data from DynamoDB based on date filter using Pyspark Glue job.

**updated** column here is in **epoch** format and is of long data type in DynamoDB.

**updated** column also has some bad data that are of **struct** data type. I would like to filter out struct data type and process only data that are of long data type.

Bad data schema:

```
|-- updated: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- long: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
```

Good data schema:

```
|-- updated: long (nullable = true)
```

Please guide me how I can filter out struct data type and retain only number data type records from a DynamoDB column.

```
datasource = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                            connection_type="dynamodb",
                            connection_options={"dynamodb.input.tableName": "retail",
                                                "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent": "0.5"},
                            transformation_ctx="datasource")
ddb_src_df = datasource.toDF()
ddb_src_df = ddb_src_df.select(from_unixtime((ddb_src_df.updated.cast('bigint')/1000)).cast('date').alias('updated'))
ddb_fnl_df = ddb_src_df.filter(ddb_src_df.updated.substr(1,10) < current_date)
```

**Error message:**

`` cannot resolve 'CAST(`updated` AS BIGINT)' due to data type mismatch:cannot cast struct<long:bigint,string:string> to bigint ``

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the `long` field value in `updated` struct, based on your error log, you should:

```
ddb_src_df = ddb_src_df.select(from_unixtime((ddb_src_df.updated.long/1000)).cast('date').alias('updated'))
```

If you're saying that, in your `ddb_src_df` dataframe, `updated` column has two different data type, one is struct and one is long type, please show sample data as it's impossible that one column can have two different schema in a dataframe or Cassandra table AFAIK.